# Passwordless ssh login on Mac OS without -i option

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I have a ssh key without a password to login to a remote system. Let's assume the remote server is called `server-name` and has the same user as the one I'm currently logged in. In the console if I do the following:

```
ssh server-name
```

A popup appears which asks me to enter my password. If I do not enter any password I get the error message `Permission denied (publickey).`

However, doing this:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_key_rsa server-name
```

works fine.

I also found on the net, that adding `AskPassGUI no` to `~/.ssh/config` prevents the popup from being shown. However, then I get the following:

```
Tom@computer:~/.ssh$ ssh server-name
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/Tom/.ssh/my_key_rsa.pub': 
Permission denied (publickey).
```

So, what do I have to do in order to login without the `-i` option?

Note: I set the correct key files in `~/.ssh/config` for accessing the corresponding remote machine, i.e.

```
Tom@computer:~/.ssh$ cat ~/.ssh/config 
AskPassGUI no
Host *
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_key_rsa.pub
```

Comment: You need to specify your private key as `IdentityFile`, not the public one.

Answer (score 3):

```
Host *
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_key_rsa.pub
```

You've specified the wrong key file here. You need to specify the *private* key file, not the *public* key file. The private key file is the one without the `.pub` extension:

```
Host *
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_key_rsa
```